# How to write the dash of discrete math in latex?

Tags: syntax

[image]

I don't know how to use dash like this. It's not \bar{}.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.  Could you show what you've tried?  It sure looks like `\bar` to me.  (And I assume we're talking about the line over `$p$, $s$, and $t$`, not the long horizontal line between the last two lines of math.)

Comment: your image looks like `\bar`  was used, but you could also try `\overline` (which tends to be longer)

Comment: I'm talking about the long horizontal line between the last two lines of math, not the $p$, ....

Comment: how were we to know that!!!  you could use a tabular for the stack of expressions and then `\hline` will draw the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated the code in your image. Maybe this is, what you were looking for:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    &p                          \\
    &\bar{p} \rightarrow q      \\
    &(q \wedge r) \rightarrow s \\
    &t \rightarrow r            \\
    \hline
    &\therefore \bar{s} \rightarrow \bar{t}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Looks like this:
[image: Image of eqotion with \hline]

In addition to his, I would recommend to put the " & " right in front of the " \rightarrow " to improve the style of the equotion:

```
\begin{aligned}
    p                  &               \\
    \bar{p}            & \rightarrow q \\
    (q \wedge r)       & \rightarrow s \\
    t                  & \rightarrow r \\
    \hline
    \therefore \bar{s} & \rightarrow \bar{t}
\end{aligned}
```